# Connecting by SFTP to a deployment server in PyCharm does not work

Tags: python, debugging, deployment, pycharm

I have configured SFTP connection with login and password in 
`PyCharm 2019.3.3 (Build #PY-193.6494.30)` on `Mac OS 10.15.3`. When I am trying "Test SFTP Connection" I get no error but a "Connecting by SFTP" loop that never times out. Everytime I reinstall PyCharm, it works for 2-3 times but after that, connections are not established anymore and I get connecting loops as described. When I reinstalled PyCharm, I made sure to delete all related files from ~/Library. The connection is being established through a VPN tunnel. I can perfectly ssh into the same deployment address, only PyCharm cannot connect.

[image]

I was able to get the following from the logs:

```
2020-03-02 15:22:42,945 [  17190]  DEBUG - t.connections.RemoteConnection - Opening connection to sftp://10.5.166.81:22/ in @6aab2a3e 
2020-03-02 15:22:42,970 [  17215]  DEBUG - ntellij.ssh.impl.SshConnection - Failed to create SSH channel using existing SSH sessions, creating new SSH session 
2020-03-02 15:22:42,970 [  17215]  DEBUG - ntellij.ssh.impl.SshConnection - Establishing new SSH session to user@10.5.166.81:22 
2020-03-02 15:22:43,186 [  17431]   INFO - port.random.BouncyCastleRandom - Generating random seed from SecureRandom. 
2020-03-02 15:22:43,603 [  17848]   INFO - z.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Client identity string: SSH-2.0-SSHJ_0.27.0 
2020-03-02 15:22:43,625 [  17870]   INFO - z.sshj.transport.TransportImpl - Server identity string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 
2020-03-02 15:22:43,821 [  18066]   INFO - om.intellij.ssh.impl.sshj.sshj - Authentication log: SSHJ connection to user@10.5.166.81:22
* With preferred authentications: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
* With signature factories: ssh-rsa, ssh-dss, ecdsa-sha2-nistp256, ecdsa-sha2-nistp384, ecdsa-sha2-nistp521, ssh-ed25519
* With keep alive interval 300 seconds
* With keep alive count max 1000
* With OpenSshLikeHostKeyVerifier(knownHostsFile=[/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts], strictHostKeyChecking=ASK, hashKnownHosts=false)
* With predefined password
* With authentications: password by net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AuthPassword, keyboard-interactive by net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AuthKeyboardInteractive
* With socketFactory com.intellij.ssh.sockets.MySftpJavaSocketFactory@630ddfb0
* With connect timeout 10000
* Connected
  => none by net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AuthNone@24b009e5 (failure, new allowed auth methods: publickey, password)
  => password by net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AuthPassword@108e1414 (success) 
2020-03-02 15:22:43,825 [  18070]  DEBUG - ntellij.ssh.impl.SshConnection - SSH session @30c953a1 established to user@10.5.166.81:22 
2020-03-02 15:22:43,825 [  18070]  DEBUG - ellij.ssh.SshConnectionService - Creating sftp channel within SshjSshConnection(<crc32=zov9y>@<crc32=1djyopl>)@30c953a1 
2020-03-02 15:22:44,628 [  18873]   INFO - .channel.direct.SessionChannel - Will request `sftp` subsystem
```

I normally login through my private ssh key but login with user+password also works:

```
$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no 10.5.166.81
The authenticity of host '10.5.166.81 (10.5.166.81)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ELdUhvqI6us+QR/CJRwb0u4a+zUcvWLUdZdWeYmhj2s.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
user@10.5.166.81's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64)
```

I noticed that for new deployment servers, PyCharm sometimes does not ask me to accept the ECDSA key fingerprint. Perhaps this might result in PyCharm endlessly trying to "Connecting by SFTP" while waiting for the user to accept the key fingerprint prompt that never shows up.

I do not use KeX algorithms so the suggested workaround [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001408159-PyCharm-unable-to-set-up-Deployment-with-a-remote-server-) can't be used.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue. The logs indicated that something was wrong with sftp. By debugging the output of `sftp -v user@10.5.166.81` I could see that authentication through SSH was working fine but sftp would stop after that. It turns out, that I had the command `zsh` in my `~/.bashrc` that worked fine for ssh sessions but not for sftp ones. Removing this line from the bashrc and instead using `chsh <user> -s /bin/zsh` solved the problem and now enables `Connecting by SFTP` successfully.

Comment: good debug tip. For me `sftp -v ...` actually worked, so I figured pycharm is being crazy and re-created the config from scratch, which solved my issues.